# Yii2 $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) не загружает из формы

Tags: php, база-данных, yii2, form

Форма получает данные $_POST, но не передает в контроллер
в ДБ могу сохранить данные если убрать условие load()

Controller

```
public function actionSend(){

        $model = new User();
                $model->getErrors();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->money = 'something';
            $model->username = 'something';
            $model->save();

        }
        return $this->render('send',[

            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
```

MODEL

```
<?php

namespace app\models;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

use Yii;

class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'money'], 'safe'],
            [['username', 'password'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
            [['auth_key', 'access_token'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['money'], 'string', 'max' => 8],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'auth_key' => 'Auth Key',
            'access_token' => 'Access Token',
            'money' => 'Money',
        ];
    }
}
```

VIEW

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
?>

<h2>Send</h2>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'layout' => 'horizontal',
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'template' => "{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-3\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
            'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1 control-label'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['name' => 'username']) ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'money')->textInput(['name' => 'money'])?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: может `if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())) {` ?

Comment: в чем разница??

Comment: ну бывает иногда... разница в неймспейсе и откуда конкретно будет браться `Yii`

Comment: конечно же это не при чем

Comment: что выводит `print_r(Yii::$app->request->post());` ?

Comment: print_r(Yii::$app->request->post());Array ( [_csrf] => oZaVdqPki04MfRu6FpLKO5iuF0Qbyr2JISzWt13d9b2Vyfgm74b_CGkSaYwgw4wW64NFG0OPyNtpRrHtFpKA7Q== [username] => 1 [money] => 1 ) 1 как я и писал ранее, $_POST принимает значения

Comment: if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '')){ а так?

Comment: пальцем в небо. if(isset($_POST['money']) && isset($_POST['username'])){ сработало, load не работает

Answer (score 2):

ПыСы, почему-то только сейчас выскочил вопрос в ленте, некропостинг детектед

У Вас тут ошибка

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['name' => 'username']) ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'money')->textInput(['name' => 'money'])?>
```

Вы назначаете инпутам новые name, что вступает в конфликт с ActiveForm, так как ActiveForm самостоятельно генерирует имена инпутов в формате ModelName[name], в итоге, когда load обрабатывает post он просто не видит массива ModelName для обработки и соответственно не загружает информацию.

Правильный код:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput() ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'money')->textInput()?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Как Вам уже правильно подсказали в комментариях - так как Вы передаете данные в виде простого массива, не вложенного подмассивом в элемент с именем формы, то нужно воспользоваться таким выражением:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '')) {
    // ...
}
```

где вторым параметром передается пустое имя формы.

Answer (score 0):

```
$model = new User();
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->money = 'something';
        $model->username = 'something';
        if ($model->save()) {
            //тут свое вставите
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('FormSubmitte');
            return $this->refresh();
        }
    }
```

Либо

```
 [['username', 'money'], 'required'],
```

Comment: Что поменялось ?

Comment: @Dima Rashevskiy  у вас $model = new User; а нужно $model = new User();

Comment: спасибо, это подправил, но не в этом дело. Опять таки возвращаюсь к вопросу - load не работает, если убрать это условие все сохраняет в бд. required стоял изначально, не работало